# Use function pointer initialized in other source file

Tags: c, callback

I have function pointer, that is declared as follows in file 1.h

```
// file : 1.h
typedef void (*my_func_ptr_T)(int , int);
```

In file 1.c I create a global instance and initialize it

```
// file 1.c
my_func_ptr_T func;

void callback (my_func_ptr_T _ptr) {
    func = _ptr;
}
```

Now, how can i use this function ptr 'func' in another file say 2.c

```
// file 2.c 
void do_callback() {
    //  i want to do this
    func(1,2);
}
```

Comment: ... and make sure you include that header file in *both* C files. That way, if you change something in the C file that defines it, you'll get a compiler error, instead of a linker error, or strange undetected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the below changes

```
// file : 1.h
typedef void (*my_func_ptr_T)(int , int);
extern my_func_ptr_T func;

//file 1.c
#include "1.h"

//func is visible


// file 2.c
#include "1.h"

//func is visible
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `2.c` to below will help. Leave `1.h` and `1.c` unchanged.

```
#include "1.h"
extern my_func_ptr_T func;

void do_callback() {
    func(1,2);
}

//sample sum function
void sum( int a, int b ) {
    printf ("SUM : %d\n", a+b);
}

//main
int main() {
    func = sum;
    do_callback( );
}
```

*It is important to understand that, keyword `extern` doesn't define the variable. It is just a variable **declaration**. No memory is allocated for an `extern` variable declaration. The `func` variable is actually **defined** in `1.c` and that is where memory is allocated. You are free to use `extern` declarations in as many files ( for e.g. `3.c`) as you need.*

Note: Careful when adding `extern` to header file as in accepted answer. That makes variable visible, in which ever source file the header in included and so a potential risk of name collisions or unintentional modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You make the variable `func` known in file 2.c:

```
// file 2.c
extern my_func_ptr_T func;

void do_callback() {
//  i want to do this
    func(1,2);
}
```

By declaring `func`as `extern` you tell the compiler that this particular variable will live in a file / different compilation unit (e.g. 1.o compiled from 1.c, where a variable of the same name and type is declared without the `extern`keyword), and it does not need to create it when compiling 2.c into 2.o.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example about using function pointers...

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void prev(int x)
 {
     printf( "%d\n", x-1 );
 }

 void next(int x)
 {
     printf( "%d\n", x+1 );
 }

 typedef void (*my_func_ptr_T)(int);

 int main()
 {
     my_func_ptr_T foo;

     foo = &prev;

     foo( 5 );

     return 0;
 }
```

You can run the code in this [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b0ed1fc237f0d6)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.